# New to JS, want to display strings

Tags: javascript

Say I have JSON object with data like this (in a separate .json file):

```
evidenceStrings = [
{"jokeid": 0, "evidence": ["\My God you're right! I never would've thought of that!", "this look that says \My God you're right! I never would've thought of that!\", " \My God you're right! I never would've thought of that!\"]},
{"jokeid": 1, "evidence": ["the man didn't have to watch"]},
{"jokeid": 2, "evidence": ["knocking down trees with your face", "knocking down trees with your face. ", " knocking down trees with your face. ", "with your face.", "knocking down trees with your face"]}
]
```

I want to display the "evidence" in an HTML file. The problem is that I'm reading content from another .js file and displaying it's content using a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jokes.length; i++) {
    // display string at index 0 of an array in a .js file
```

`i` here refers to the `jokeid` in the JSON object. Now what I want is, that for the given `i`, extract my `evidence` from the JSON object, and display it (preferably with a newline after every string.

Comment: You have an array of javascript objects, there is no JSON here

Comment: Is that the whole file? You are trying to iterate over an array `jokes` which isn't defined here.

Comment: Are you saying your separate file actually includes the `evidenceStrings = ` part? Will the objects in that array always be in order, or are you asking how to search through an arbitrarily sorted array to find a particular item? Note that [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: What is with the random \'s?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole file, and my partner said it's a JSON. I should have begun with this: I have no js experience. And yes, they will always be in order. The random \'s are part of the file.

Comment: If that's the whole file, then your code will fail with a ReferenceError since there's no `jokes` variable declared. And actually, you'll get a SyntaxError for the missing `}`

Comment: Well there's a `jokes.js` file with `jokes = ["some", "text", "here"]`. The number of strings in `jokes` = size of the `evidenceStrings` array

Answer (score 1):

This requires looping over `evidenceStrings` to see whether the matching jokeid is found.  You can do this nicely with `.filter`, but internally it essentially does the same thing.

```
for (var x = 0; x < jokes.length; x++) {
    var id = jokes[x];
    evidence = evidenceStrings.filter(function (elem) {
        return +elem.jokeid == id;
    });
    if (evidence.length == 1 && evidence[0].hasOwnProperty('evidence')) {
        console.log(evidence[0].evidence.join("\n"));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cFsze/

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore to simplify these things (http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var foundJoke = _.find(evidenceStrings,function(item) {
   return item.jokeid === 0;
});

var firstItem = _.first(foundJoke.evidence);    
if(_.isArray(foundJoke.evidence)) alert(foundJoke.evidence.join('\n'));
```

or

```
var foundJoke = _.findWhere(evidenceStrings,{jokeid:0});
```